# Included JS in iframe has context of top frame window

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, dynamic-loading

```
$('<script/>', {
    src: '/path/to/javascript.js',
    type: 'text/javascript'
}).appendTo($('#iframe').contents().find('body'));
```

Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think that should load the JS into the iframe. I've also tried appending to `head`.

**The problem**
`javascript.js` is executed, but `console.debug(this)` in that script returns the top frame window. I've tried to verify that the script is actually included in the iframe, but don't really know how.

[image: firebug output]

Additionally, running `$('a')` from `javascript.js` returns all links in the top frame, not every link in the iframe which I'd like.

Thanks for your time!

---

**Update:** I've put together [an isolated test case](http://labs2.mimmin.com/other/iframe-dyn-load/) which [you also can download](http://labs2.mimmin.com/other/iframe-dyn-load/iframe-dyn-load.zip). Check the console and note that this is the top frame (can be verified by the variable _TOP).

Comment: is the iframe in the same domain, bc if its not you have cross-domain issues

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a grey area. For this specific action using jQuery, under the hood you're using `importNode` or `adoptNode` depending on the browser. However, IE won't support either (since I last researched it).

You might want to get a reference to the document, and write the script. If memory serves me right:

```
$('<iframe/>')[0].contentDocument.document.write('script');
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to make something in the same domain iframe update:
http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/DX6bg/1/

Make sure that the two URLs are in the same domain.
(including if there is a `www` in from or not)

**UPDATE**

You can test it like this:

```
$(function(){
   var iframe = $('#iframe').contents();

   $('body', iframe).append($('<div>', {text: 'this is a test'}));
});
```

now if you see the text `this is a test` in the iframe you know it is working

Comment: Hm not sure what you want to show with this. Could you please explain how this fixes the context issue?

Comment: @Znarkus, can you show us the page so we can see the errors, i was showing you that your code works, i think you might have cross-domain issues

Comment: I've put together an [isolated test case](http://labs2.mimmin.com/other/iframe-dyn-load/) which you [also can download](http://labs2.mimmin.com/other/iframe-dyn-load/iframe-dyn-load.zip). Check the console and note that `this` is the top frame (can be verified by the variable _TOP).

Comment: Try wrapping the jquery with `$(function(){/*your code here*/})`

Comment: what are these line `console.debug on "this" from iframe.js:  
DOMWindow` coming from?

Comment: Your js is working. it just doesnt show the script tags. i tried it using the console on your site. try adding another tag, and it workis. also the console logs from iframe.js do show up (in chrome at least they do)

Comment: I don't think you understand the problem. Yes, the JS file is loaded. But not into the iframe because `DOMWindow` is not the iframe, it's the iframe's parent (the top window).

Comment: @Znarkus, no `DOMWindow` and if you look inside it it has a parent which is also `DomWindow`

Comment: @Neal Yes even the the top window will have a parent, [but it points to itself](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/window.parent).

Comment: whatever. im done. your code works. you just dont want to accept that ^_^